# How can I run selenium scripts on Edge headless browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, microsoft-edge, headless-browser, selenium-edgedriver

I want to run my scripts in Edge browser in headless mode.But I am not able to find any proper solution for it.
Can anyone suggest on this

Comment: What research have you done to not be able to find any help on this? Google is your friend my friend. Try entering "edge selenium"

Answer (score 2):

Here, I assume that you are trying to automate the MS Edge Chromium browser and you want to run selenium tests on the MS Edge browser in headless mode.

You can refer to the steps below.

1. Download the Java/C# binding of Selenium 4.00-alpha05 from [here](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
2. Download the matching version of Microsoft Edge Driver from [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads).

Example C# code.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using System.Threading;
namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class edgewebdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
            edgeOptions.UseChromium = true;
            edgeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";
            edgeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
            edgeOptions.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
            var msedgedriverDir = @"E:\webdriver";
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(msedgedriverDir, edgeOptions);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("<website url>");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

JAVA Example code:

```
package selenium_test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.*;

public class new_java_class 
{
        public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","D:\\edgedriver_win64_83.0.478.45\\msedgedriver.exe");
         EdgeOptions op=new EdgeOptions();
                 op.addArguments("headless");
                 WebDriver browser = new EdgeDriver(op);
                 browser.get("https://microsoft.com");

    }
}
```

Note: Change the paths and modify the values in above code as per your own requirements.

You can download the Selenium 4.00-alpha05 on any path. you need to add it in your JAVA project by **add External Jars** option.

[image]

Comment: Can I get t in Java as I am using Java in my framework.And using this code I am getting errors. Also, on which path I  download this Java/C# binding of Selenium 4.00-alpha05

Comment: Please refer to the updated answer. I have added the JAVA code sample.

Comment: I am not able to set values to edgeoptions. it says UseChromium ,BinaryLocation  etc are not member of edgeoptions. any idea? i have done the import correctly  as Imports OpenQA.Selenium.Edge

Comment: Does chromium Edge support headless execution if launched in IE Capability Mode?

Comment: Running the Edge chromium-browser in IE mode will put the whole browser in an IE mode. Headless execution is not supported by the IE browser. so it will also not work when you try to automate the Edge chromium-browser in an IE mode.

Comment: This didn't work, the browser window is still getting opened. And addArguments() method is not present in *org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions* but its in *com.microsoft.edge.seleniumtools.EdgeOptions*

Comment: Is it possible do run Edge in headless mode with Selenium 3.x?

Answer (score -1):

For python 3 this will enable headless browsing in edge:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=opt)
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Using Python, that would be:

```
# Imports
from selenium import webdriver

# Instantiate a EdgeOption object
edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

# Set headless mode
edge_options.headless = True

# Start driver, passing edge_options
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)

# Get page
page = driver.get(r"https://www.google.com")
```

This should work. Good luck!

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work