# How to config and open MS Edge Headless browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge, chromium, microsoft-edge-chromium

I have requriment to open the Application in MS Edge headless browser, I googled but no luck didn't find proper guidance. please provide how we can start and load url in Edge headless browser.

Environment I have tried **(Selenium + Java)**

windows 10 or 7

Selenium version : 3.141.59

**Java** : 1.8 and 11

Edge Browser version : 88.0.705.81 (Official build) (64-bit) (Chromium)

Edege Driver version : 87.0.664.55 /  88.0.705.81

these 2 below methods are mentioned in some blogs both are showing errors AND does not belong to JAVA+EDGE+Headless combo

EdgeOptions op = new EdgeOptions();

op.useChromium =true;

op.addArguments("headless");

both are showing as wrong in IDE.

please shed light on this topic.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/puppeteer/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run selenium scripts on Edge headless browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62278888/how-can-i-run-selenium-scripts-on-edge-headless-browser)

Comment: I have verified that my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62279329/10309381) still works fine. You can try to refer to it. The answer contains detailed configuration steps and sample code. If the issue still persists then I suggest you replace the Selenium 3.141.59 with the [Selenium 4.0.0-beta-1](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/4.0-beta-1/selenium-java-4.0.0-beta-1.zip). Also, make sure that you are using the compatible and correct version of the webdriver. See whether it helps to fix the issue. Let us know about your test results.